# Rails href with hash value not updating url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm using [Materialize Tabs](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html) and have everything working fine, except the fact that my URL doesn't update when I click a tab link. I have the following two links:

```
<ul id="db-tabs" class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a class="tab-text active" href="#activegroups">Active Groups</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a class="tab-text" href="#submittedgroups">Submitted Groups</a></li>
</ul>
```

Yet when I click one of these links, the URL remains unchanged. I would have expected the URL to change to something like `/admin#submittedgroups`, yet is just remains `/admin`.

If I manually enter the url `/admin#submittedgroups`, i'll get taken to the correct tab but otherwise the URL never changes.

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript library you're using [is preventing the default action](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/js/tabs.js#L201), including the default browser navigation. You'll need to manually update the URL with javascript if this is your desired behavior, or use a different library.